# Painting text over background image is dim

Tags: android, text, canvas, drawtext

I'm painting text over a background image on a canvas. I move the image interactively (like a Ouija board pointer). I've set the canvas to black, the pointer is red and I want to write white text over it so that the pointer has a player's name on it.

In Android 2.3.4 it appears as solid white text on top of the red pointer which is pretty clear, but I'd like to use any color. In Android 4.1.2 I can barely see the white text. Here's my code:

```
    public Pointer(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paintBg = new Paint();
    paintBg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paintName = new Paint();
    paintName.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paintName.setTextSize(50); // set text size
    paintName.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paintName.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    this.setImageResource(res); // pointer.png in res/drawable folder
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(res);
    h = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
    w = d.getIntrinsicWidth();

    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.drawPaint(paintBg);//make background black

    // float imageScale = width / w; // how image size scales with screen
}


@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    y = this.getHeight() / 2; // center of screen
    x = this.getWidth() / 2;
    int left = Math.round(x - 0.8f * w);
    int right = Math.round(x + 0.8f * w);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate((direction + 180) % 360, x, y); // rotate to normal
    canvas.drawText(s, x, y + 20, paintName); // draw name

    canvas.restore();
    canvas.rotate(direction, x, y); // rotate back
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

What changed in 4.1.2 that would affect this, or am I doning something incorrectly? Thanks for your help with this as it's driving me crazy.

Edit to include screen shots:

Android 2.3.4
[image: 2.3.4 Image]

Android 4.1.2
[image: 4.1.2 Image]

Note how the white text appears to be on top in 2.3.4 while it appears below or muddy in 4.1.2.

As free3dom pointes out it is related to alpha.  I do change alpha because if I don't, the text does not appear on top of the arrow. It appears that the ImageView having the pointer image is always on top - could this be what's going on?
Here is how I handle setting alpha:

```
    public static void setAlpha(View view, float alpha, int duration) {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
    final AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(alpha, alpha);
    animation.setDuration(duration);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animation);
 } else                          //for 11 and above
    view.setAlpha(alpha);
}
```

Maybe it has something to do with using this.setImageResource(res) to set the image resource? According to android developer guide, I can only set alpha to the single view and everything in the view is changed. Yet if I lower the alpha, the arrow image seems to become transparent enough to allow me to see the text.

Comment: Based on the new info it seems that your render order is the problem. Is there a way for you to render the arrow **before** you render the text?

Comment: The arrow is instantiated as part of the creation of the imageview class. All text writing is done after that during that class's onDraw method. I've looked through developer docs, but can't see how to control render order. Very frustrating...

Comment: Have you tried moving the `super.onDraw(canvas);` to the top of your `onDraw` method?

Comment: Just tried it. The text appears on top! but now the arrow does not move and they need to move together. Good idea though.  I've tried using animation to move the arrow but can't find a way to build it when drawing the name before animating it as one image.

Comment: Then maybe just duplicate the transformation of the canvas before the `super.onDraw()` call and then do it again for the text - it may be redundant but sometimes that is how to get things done :)

Comment: That didn't work either. There is something fundamentally different with how the canvas is drawn in 4.1.2 vs 2.3.4. I've searched but still have no clue. Thanks Free3dom for all the great suggestions, but I'm abandoning this approach. I'll post it a different way.

Comment: No problem, and good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

You set a stroke width, but never indicate that stroke should be used for the `Paint`.

Try adding

`paintName.setStyle( FILL_AND_STROKE );`

Comment: Thanks free3dom. That enhances the text on 2.3.4 but has no effect on making it appear more clearly on top of the background pointer in 4.1.2. There must be something I'm doing wrong for 4.1.2.

Comment: Try using [setSubpixelText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setSubpixelText%28boolean%29) to see if that makes a difference in 4.1.2. Also, a screenshot of the problem in 4.1.2 would be helpful to identify the issue.

Comment: I tried to post screenshots but I don't have enough reputation points :(
Setting setSubpixelText(isEnabled) made no difference.

Comment: Post a link to the screenshot in a comment here (add some spaces/whatever so it doesn't look like a link, if needed) then I will edit your question and add the screenshot.

Comment: Okay I have added the images to your post. By the look of it it seems to be opacity related. Try adding a `paintName.setAlpha(255);` after `paintName.setColor(Color.WHITE);`. Alternately use the `paintName.setARGB(255,255,255,255)` instead of both those calls.